# SQL nested select sum returns wrong integer

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have the following select statement:

```
   SELECT 
    T.name,
    C.name as competence_name,
    THC.competence_level_id as requiredLevel,
    (SELECT SUM(UHC.competence_level_id) FROM user_has_competence UHC INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = UHC.user_id WHERE competence_id = C.id AND U.title_id = T.id GROUP BY T.id) as current_level,
    (SELECT 
            ROUND(SUM(UHC.competence_level_id)/ COUNT(UHC.user_id)) 
        FROM
            user_has_competence UHC
        JOIN user U ON U.id = UHC.user_id
        WHERE
            competence_id = C.id
                AND U.title_id = T.id GROUP BY T.id) - THC.competence_level_id as gap,
C.id
FROM
    title_has_competence THC
        JOIN
    title T ON T.id = THC.title_id
        JOIN
    competence C ON C.id = THC.competence_id
```

This returns the following result:

```
    'Head of IT', 'Office', '7', '16', '1', '524'
'Head of IT', 'Empatisk', '2', '5', '1', '527'
'Head of IT', 'Målrettet', '5', '12', '1', '529'
'Head of IT', 'Udadvendt', '10', NULL, NULL, '525'
'Webudvikler', 'Office', '2', '3', '1', '524'
'Webudvikler', 'Outlook', '3', '4', '1', '526'
'Webudvikler', 'Målrettet', '6', '10', '4', '529'
'Webudvikler', 'Back-end', '9', '9', '0', '534'
'Webudvikler', 'Infosoft', '10', '5', '-5', '532'
```

However the result is invalid:

In the first row you will see the current level sum is = `16` this should  be 9 (6 + 3)

The gap is also incorrect as the gap should be `9 / 2 = 4.5 - 7 = -2.5`

So my question is what am i doing wrong? why is my `SUM()` function returning way to much.

Also note that the `COUNT()` returns the right value = `2`

### **The Tables**

**title_has_competence**

```
 id    title_id competence_id competence_level_id
'82', '165', '527', '2'
'85', '166', '524', '2'
'86', '166', '526', '3'
'83', '165', '529', '5'
'87', '166', '529', '6'
'81', '165', '524', '7'
'88', '166', '534', '9'
'84', '165', '525', '10'
'89', '166', '532', '10'
```

**User_has_competence**

```
 user_id, competence_id, competence_level_id, progression
'1', '524', '6', '0'
'1', '527', '4', '0'
'1', '529', '3', '0'
'2', '524', '10', '0'
'2', '527', '1', '0'
'2', '529', '9', '0'
'3', '524', '3', '0'
'3', '526', '4', '0'
'3', '529', '10', '0'
'3', '532', '5', '0'
'3', '534', '9', '0'
```

**title**

```
 id,   name       organization_id
'165', 'Head of IT', '1'
'166', 'Webudvikler', '1'
```

**User**

```
id, username, password, title_id,
1   **      , **       ,  165
2   **      , **      ,   165
3   **      , **     ,    166
```

Comment: can you provide tables it is difficult to judge

Comment: @koushikveldanda Ofcourse one moment